# Adding property to objects before sending response

Tags: node.js, arrays

I am trying to add another property to each object I receive from the DynamoDB table. I am trying to do this by altering each object in the Items array then adding the Items array to my responseBody. All I get in return is the original items without any new properties. This could be a product of me using the array functions or spread operator incorrectly, just kindly point out anything you may see. My lambda function is below:

```
const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    data.Items.map(item => {
      item = {
        ...item,
        control: control_id
      };
    });
responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
```

UPDATE: I solved my issue above by doing the following:

```
const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    data.Items.forEach(item => {
      item.control = control_id;
    });
responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Array Map return new array.
see [Array Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: okay, got it. I was under the impression it was altering it. Thanks